# Dependency analysis from C# code through to database tables/columns

Tags: c#, database, sql, dependency-analysis

I'm looking for a tool to do system wide dependency analysis in C# code and [SQL Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server) databases.  It's looking like the only tool available that does this might be CAST ([CAST software](http://www.castsoftware.com/)), which is expensive and it does **lots** more besides that I don't really need.

C# code through to database column dependency would be hugely useful for many reasons, including:
 - determining effects of database changes throughout the system
 - seeing hot spots in the database schema
 - finding dead stored procedures, tables, etc.
 - understanding the existing code base

Do such tools exist?

Comment: This is really difficult when dynamic SQL is generated.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can hack it yourself with the database's system information tables, and e.g. ReSharper's PSI-module for analyzing C# code; given that you call SProcs and SQL in a fairly common manner, you could then join the call sites with the sproc's meta-data to see what would affect what.

(; In general though, it seems to be a good idea to start moving away from sprocs as much as possible. I remember there was a heated debate won by the code-not-sprocs crowd in 2006. ;)